# Js callback is ignored in metamask pay confirmed - if multiple payments in popup

Tags: web3js, blockchain, metamask

When paying via MetaMask, a situation may arise when there are several unconfirmed payments.
[image]
[image]

The problem is that in this case, when one of the transactions is confirmed, the js callback is ignored. Js starts processing only after the last transaction is confirmed. As a result, two transactions are paid instead of one.

Tell me how to make sure that all transactions in the pop-up window are not ignored and are picked up in js.

I repeat: transactions are ignored by js - if there are several of them in popup, only the last transaction is processed. Most likely you need to add something in the js code, only I don’t know what.

source code:

```
const trans = signer.sendTransaction(tx).then( async function (res) {
            $(".pay-process-description").show();
            App.saveTransaction(res.hash, orderId);
            payIsReturnTransactionId = false;
            setTimeout(App.checkPayIsExpired, 120000, orderId);
            return res.wait();
        }).then(function (tx) {
            payIsReturnTransactionId = true;
            App.checkAndPay(tx.transactionHash, orderId); 
        }).catch(function (error) {
            if (error.code =="4001"){
               App.cancelPay(orderId);
            } else {
               App.errorPay(orderId, error.code);
            }
        });
```